# Getting error on using refreshToken for googleAPI to get new access token

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth

My code to get the access token using a refresh token was working fine, but suddenly has stopped working and I'm getting exception as

> unauthorized client and status code as 401.

Below is my sample code:

```
request({
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
                 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
        data: {
               client_id: XXXXX,
               client_secret: XXXXX,
               refresh_token: myRefresh_Token_Here,
                grant_type: 'refresh_token'
              },
        URL: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
      })
                .then(response => {
                    resolve(response);
            })
            .catch(exception => {
                reject(exception);
            });
```

Below is the error what i get
this i get in below object

```
exception.response.data
{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Unauthorized"}'
```

No other info, also the status code is **401**

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full error message there should be more.   There are several unauthorized client errors it would be helpful to nail down which one it is you are getting.  check for an error description

Answer (score 1):

> unauthorized client

Normally means that the client id and client secret you are using to pair with a refresh token is not the pair that was used to create the refresh token in the first place.

I would double check you have the correct client id and client secret or that someone didn't regenerate your secret on Google cloud console.

Comment: @DalmTo yes indeed, i have checked those possibilities. ClientId ClientSecret are all right, also the same was used to generate the refreshToken

Comment: @DalmTo i have observed that, when the access token has expired, and then i try to use refreshToken to get my new accessToken then im getting unauthorized Client, whereas if the accessToken has not expired and if i use the refreshToken to get the new access_token in this case it works fine and i gets the new accessToken

Comment: Then the issue is with your Refresh token.  I suspect that you did not create this refresh token with this client id, client secret, it could also be that the user has revoked your access. Try generating a new refresh token and test again.